Each thread is slower when more threads are present
I have 16 files I need to read from and process the data. All of data is independent. This is a snippet of code that processes that data:
int threadCount = 1;
ConcurrentBag<SomeClass> items = new ConcurrentBag<SomeClass>();

Parallel.For(0, threadCount, i =>
{
     string[] itemsInfo = File.ReadAllLines("itemInfo" + i + ".txt");
     int index = 0;
     Console.WriteLine("Loading items...");
     List<SomeClass> threadItems = new List<SomeClass>();
     while (itemsInfo[index] != "<!---ITEMS END---!>")
     {
           SomeClass item = new SomeClass();
           index = item.FromString(itemsInfo, index);
           threadItems .Add(item);

           if (i == 0)
           {
              Console.WriteLine("Reading " + item.Id);
           }
     }

     foreach (SomeClass item in threadItems )
     {
          items .Add(item);
     }
});

The problematic part is the while loop. SomeClass.FromString just does some string parsing, it only relies data within the string.
If I run the snippet as show, with threadCount 1, it processes roughly about 20 items per second. If I change threadCount to 16 (CPU I'm using does have 16 virtual cores), it slows down to roughly one item per second.
Note that, in both cases, exactly the same file is being processed. The only difference is that in second case, 15 additional threads are all processing their own files.
I can confirm that all the threads were within the while loop when I measured the speed. I can also confirm that RAM wasn't filled at the time. I can also say that what I observed applies to any number of threads between 1 and 16, the more threads there are, the slower the first one is.
What else could it be?

what is Parallel.For ? The tag you used is for a .NET method

Virtual cores are often not physical cores but hardware threads. Using SMT can sometimes slowdown an application. This is very specific to the exact code executed (which is not provided). The same thing applies for scalability actually. I also do not expect a code doing a lot of new to scale well (AFAIK no parallel GCs scale well nor fully-shared allocators) unless objects are locals. Btw, if there are some locks in your code, it can be slower with many threads due to a lock contention (more generally resources contention).

You should probably profile your code to see where it's taking that time...

Did you try to remove the Console.WriteLine ? I could imagine trouble there.

Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach are meant for data parallelism while this code seems to be purely IO-bound. Data parallelism means processing lots of in-memory data using all available cores with minimal synchronization. They do this by partitioning the data and using one worker task per partition. They don't start threads, they start worker tasks, with each processing its own partition. The question's code on the other hand blocks the CPU cores while waiting for the disk to retrieve file contents

What is the actual work you want to perform? You could speed up processing by using eg TransformBlock and ActionBlock in a pipeline, with one or more TransformBlocks loading files asynchronously, processing them in parallel with an ActionBlock at the end storing the results to the final destination

Only 20 items per second?!?  What are new SomeClass(); and index = item.FromString(itemsInfo, index); actually doing?  "does some string parsing" doesn't tell the whole story.  You should be able to get hundreds of thousands of items per second.

foreach (SomeClass item in threadItems ) { items .Add(item); } is not an appropriate access pattern for a concurrent collection.  Just add the list itself to the bag.  Flatten the collection later, if you even need to.

The problem is within the while loop. All the files in all the threads are loaded within a few seconds on all threads (which I can detect due to a print of "Loading Items...").
The copying of items from the local list into the bag is also not a problem, since slowdown happens within the while loop, before that foreach is even reached, in any thread. That foreach is the only part where threads could interfere with each other directly (by writing to a shared resource).

As a side note, the ConcurrentBag<T> is one of the worst ways to collect the results of a parallel execution. See this answer for an explanation and alternatives. In your case you could also use PLINQ, and get the results as the output of the query (example).

@Karlovsky120 - Please provide us with a [mcve].

Also using the toExclusive parameter of the Parallel.For as a way to limit the degree of parallelism is idiomatic. The semantic way to enforce this policy is the ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism property.

16 x 1 item per sec is roughly the same as 1 x 20 items per second. Adding threads didn't speed up the process, but it didn't slow it down either. Your hard drive (even if it's SSD) is the bottleneck. It can't run faster than it does. To prove my point, try to read all the data for all the threads before you run Parallel.For and then measure performance running with one and with 16 threads. This time 16 threads should finish faster, because the slowest (and non-parallelizable) part was taken out of the measurement.
If you had 16 SSD drives with each file on separate drive, the next bottleneck would be the memory bus. There is only one of them, and all the data must run through it.

The disk is not the bottleneck since I confirmed that all threads were within the while loop at the time of the slowdown. The whole file is read at the start of all threads and loaded into memory by the time while loop is reached.

There's not enough data to tell for sure what is going on. Possible issues: "virtual" in virtual cores; some shared memory is in lock; memory swapping; hidden I/O stuff...

Each file has about 100MB. This means that the loaded string array of each thread has about 100MB. But could access to 1.6GB of data across 16 threads cause as much of a slowdown? Enough for it to seem that everything is being done on a single thread?
It happens with only two threads as well (although not as drastically, it pretty much scales linearly), happens after all IO is done and before any shared memory is written to (or accessed at all for that matter).

You can try several things.

Read all the files in advance. If they're big, your memory will be pressured and this could cause GC collections, slowing things overall. In that case,
Stream the files so memory pressure is avoided.
Change the foreach to threadItems.AddRange(). The looping across threads is likely causing contention.
Tweak the parallelization with a thread scheduler.

A more radical approach would be to open the file streams outside of the loop and pipeline each line to a queue. That isolates IO. The queue can have multiple consumers process the items (CPU-bound). TPL Dataflow is one way to do this more idiomatically.
And finally, benchmark, benchmark, benchmark.

IO was never the problem, as I mentioned in the question itself, slowdown happens after all threads are done with reading their respective files. It also happens before they reach the part of the code where they accessed the shared resource (the concurrent bag).
Each file has about 100MB, is it possible that RAM is the bottleneck? There is about 20GB free when running the program. But I don't believe that fetching 1.6GB of data from RAM could cause as much of a slowdown when spread across 16 threads, could it?

The point about the files is that you'll have memory pressure in itemsInfo instances for the life of your processing. GC running and contention on items would be my guess without benchmarking.

Simply adding more threads for tasks to be completed on does not automatically improve speed. The type of task being performed needs to be taken into account. In many cases, the overhead of creating the new threads is more costly than the benefit of doing work on multiple threads. This is often the case for operations which are not very computationally expensive.
Parallelisation is also not beneficial for operations that have a bottleneck, which in this case might be the PC disk. HDDs are generally slower than SSDs when it comes to parallel reading but it also depends on the disk specs.
Also the fact that you have 16 virtual cores and not actual cores will mean that parallelising work will not provide as much benefit as you might expect on a machine with multiple physical cores.
It's possible that the operation you need to do is not of the kind that will experience any performance benefit with parallelisation.

I said the problem scales with the number of cores. The slowdown is there even if I use only two threads, and that many physical cores I have.
Also, I'm talking about the thread doing the exact same amount of work in case when there is no parallelization opposed to the case where there is.
When I turn off the parallelization (i.e. use just a single thread), only one of the sixteen existing files is processed. When I turn it on, the thread I'm printing from is processing the same file, but is somehow slower.

If it's not a task that benefits from parallelisation then any parallelisation might cause a slow down.
